# Using a Form to Create an Object That's Pushed Into an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, object

I have an array:

```
var array = [
    {id: "X", numberA: 1, numberB: 2, dif: 1},
    {id: "Y", numberA: 2, numberB: 3, dif: 1},
    {id: "Z", numberA: 3, numberB: 5, dif: 2},
]
```

I also have a form:

```
<form id="agenda_form">
    <p>ID</p>
    <input type="text" id="id">
    <p>Start<p>
    <input type="number" id="numberA">
    <p>End</p>
    <input type="number" id="numberB">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitForm">
</form>
```

I'm trying to use that form to create an object and push that object into my array. Dif I can calculate by subtracting numberB from number A.

I've tried with jQuery and .val() but can't seem to figure it out. How would I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: I tried a version of Will's example from below. The submit button wasn't working and with his it's still not working. I'll try the other answer too.

Comment: Please add what you've tried to your post. That will help us diagnose your issue.

Comment: jsve - Got it to work! The issue was actually outside of the push method. It was caused by something else I was attempting. Thanks though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this?

```js
var array = [
    {id: "X", numberA: 1, numberB: 2, dif: 1},
    {id: "Y", numberA: 2, numberB: 3, dif: 1},
    {id: "Z", numberA: 3, numberB: 5, dif: 2},
]

$("#agenda_form").on("submit", function(e) {
  
  var numA = $("#numberA").val(),
      numB = $("#numberB").val();
  
  var obj = {
    id: "", //whatever you need,
    numberA: numA,
    numberB: numB,
    dif: numB - numA
  };
  
  array.push(obj);
  
  //Prevent page from submitting
  return false;
  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.Put this into your page.

**HTML CODE**

```
<form id="agenda_form">
<p>ID</p>
<input type="text" id="id">
<p>Start<p>
<input type="number" id="numberA">
<p>End</p>
<input type="number" id="numberB">
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="submitForm">
</form>
```

**JS CODE**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var array = [
{id: "X", numberA: 1, numberB: 2, dif: 1},
{id: "Y", numberA: 2, numberB: 3, dif: 1},
{id: "Z", numberA: 3, numberB: 5, dif: 2},
];

$('#submitForm').on('click', function(){
  var id = $('#id'),
  numberA = $('#numberA'),
  numberB = $('#numberB');

 var k =  {id:'', numberA: '', numberB: '', dif: ''};
  k.id = id.val();
  k.numberA = numberA.val();
  k.numberB = numberB.val();
  k.dif = parseInt(k.numberB) - parseInt(k.numberA);
  array.push(k);

 });
});
```